# Bar Code Scanner API

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Barcode Scanning, Options? Zxing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607858/android-barcode-scanning-options-zxing)
>   [Android: Is there a way to implement the barcode scanner into an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739550/android-is-there-a-way-to-implement-the-barcode-scanner-into-an-app)

I am planning to integrate a barcode reader to my application. Is there already an android API for that?

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app) might interest you too..

Comment: Update: Android has a barcode scanner as of August14, 2015. See  http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html for more details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update: Barcode Detection is now available in [Google Play services](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html).  [Code lab](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#1), [api docs](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview), [and a sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision).

There is no API in android. You have to use third party libraries. You can try [Zxing.](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) There are lot of discussions related to barcode scanning on stackoverflow. Search for them. Few are 
[Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app).

[Android: Is there a way to implement the barcode scanner into an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739550/android-is-there-a-way-to-implement-the-barcode-scanner-into-an-app)

Comment: I made a barcode reader library using the Google Vision API for those interested https://www.github.com/EdwardvanRaak/MaterialBarcodeScanner

Comment: Google mobile vision is now deprecated and replaced by ML Kit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning It provides sdks on both android and iOS and is getting actively improved with the latest google technology. For android, it provides sdks that can bundle the model and also provides SDK that can fetch model from Google play service automatically if you want to save your app's size.

Answer (score 5):

**No, Android doesn't have any inbuilt bar-code scanner api**. I think use [Zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) it support many formats for scanner. Also its now integrated for Android. So you can easily use this..